# Difference between calling a function using dot notation vs. using it as an argument in the function itself?

Tags: python, methods

I have some code that performs a basic Depth-First Search:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.children = []
        self.name = name

    def addChild(self, name):
        self.children.append(Node(name))   #recall I came across this before- 'Node(name)' is a node
        return self

    def depthFirstSearch(self, array): #self in this case is the root
        array.append(self.name)
        for child in self.children: 
            child.depthFirstSearch(array)
        return array
```

My question is around the second last line `child.depthFirstSearch(array)`, instead of this, can we do `depthFirstSearch(child,array)`? Would these be equivalent, because the latter is how I normally would call the function, instead of using dot notation.

I can see one reason why it would not really make sense, because for the third last line we would have `child.children`, which doesn't exist?

Lastly, when do we use dot notation in general? Or is it not necessary if we don't want to use it.

Comment: I believe you could write: `Node.depthFirstSearch(child,array)`, but your should stick with what you have.

Comment: Thanks quamrana, but my question is, can I avoid the dot notation entirely?

Comment: Or is it necessary for the DFS

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of how `depthFirstSearch()` is called on the `root` node?

Comment: The `dot` notation is how you access attributes associated with an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is, yes, you can remove the dot notation around `depthFirstSearch()`, but it would be considered slightly worse than what you have now:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.children = []
        self.name = name

    def addChild(self, name):
        self.children.append(Node(name))   #recall I came across this before- 'Node(name)' is a node
        return self

    def depthFirstSearch(self, array): #self in this case is the root
        array.append(self.name)
        for child in self.children: 
            child.depthFirstSearch(array)
        return array

# Free function version of depthFirstSearch()
def depthFirstSearch(node, array):
    array.append(node.name)
    for child in node.children: 
        depthFirstSearch(child, array)
    return array

root = Node('root')   # My guess at how you generate a root

...   # Add more children to root and more children to those Nodes

array = root.depthFirstSearch([])  #My guess at how you call this now

array = depthFirstSearch(root, [])   #You can call the free function like this
```

The reason why your original code is preferred is that the free function accesses attributes that it shouldn't need to know about. There is the name of the Node: `node.name` and the children of the Node: `node.children`

Comment: Ahh yes, I've pieced it together now! Thanks Quamrana- it is the root = Node('root') that I would normally use. Thanks